# Clang removing dead code during static linking (gcc equivalent of -Wl, --gc-sections)

Tags: macos, clang, static-linking

I'm linking against a static library and I wonder how one should handle stripping of dead code in llvm/Clang. I can't find any documentation that hints that Clang has some equivalent of -Wl, --gc-section or -dead_strip.

I assume that some dead code elimination is performed automatically at the higher optimisation levels, but that's the case in gcc too, right? Yet, gcc provides some explicit control of this via the above mentioned flags. Does Clang not provide that or am I missing something?

(The system is OSX)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dead stripping is a linker feature, not a compiler feature.  Neither gcc nor clang have it, as a result.  That's why you had to use `-Wl` - you're passing that flag to the linker.  The Mac OS X linker uses `-dead_strip`.  You can pass the flag directly to your clang invocation and it will pass it through automatically.

Comment: `-fdce` probably refers to a similar optimization carried out *within* each function by the compiler.  It's quite common for the compiler to be able to prove that individual basic blocks are dead.

Comment: Yes sorry for not being clear on that. My "optimisation-level-argument" referred to -fdce, which I thought was run by the compiler and not by the linker. But thank you for your reply - it seems that dead_strip is the command to pass to the linker and it did indeed reduce the size of the binary some (it was only documented in gcc's man pages and not clang's though. I should have been reading the man pages of ld to get what flags it accepted rather than expecting the compiler manual to include what flags can be sent :) ).